# googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append function replaces the same row over and over again instead of creating a new row

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Im creating a webscraper using puppeteer and the output goes to google sheets. The problem I'm encountering a lot of times is when I'm appending, normally it would create a new row and insert the data. But in some cases the results would appear staircase and currently

```html
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
                auth,
                spreadsheetId,
                range: "ECTRIMS v2",
                valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
                resource: {
                    values: [[sEventID,slastWideoutEdit,scongressName,scongressfullEventName,
                        scongressAbbrev,scongressLocation,scongressCity,scongressCountry,scongressYear,
                        scongressStartDate,scongressEndDate,scongressTime,scongressUrl,scongressUrlQuality,
                        scongressTwitterHashtag,scongressPresenters,scongressHCPAttendees,scongressVirtual,
                        scongressType,spresenterFirstName,spresenterMiddleName,spresenterLastName,spresenterDegrees,
                        spresenterCity,spresenterState,spresenterCountry,spresenterInstitution,spresenterBio,spresenterRole,
                        spresenterPresentationType,spresenterPresentationID,spresenterPresentationAbstract,spresenterPresentationAbstractQuality,
                        spresenterPresentationUrl,spresenterPresentationUrlQuality,spresenterOralPoster,spresenterSessionTitle,
                        spresentationDate,spresentationStartTime,spresentationEndTime,spresentationTitle,spresentationAbstract]],
                },
            });
```

It replaces the same row instead of appending. But when I use strings it just work normally.

```html
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
                auth,
                spreadsheetId,
                range: "ECTRIMS v2",
                valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
                resource: {
                    values: [["sEventID","slastWideoutEdit","scongressName","scongressfullEventName",
                        "scongressAbbrev","scongressLocation","scongressCity","scongressCountry","scongressYear",
                        "scongressStartDate","scongressEndDate","scongressTime","scongressUrl","scongressUrlQuality",
                        "scongressTwitterHashtag","scongressPresenters","scongressHCPAttendees","scongressVirtual",
                        "scongressType","spresenterFirstName","spresenterMiddleName","spresenterLastName","spresenterDegrees",
                        "spresenterCity","spresenterState","spresenterCountry","spresenterInstitution","spresenterBio","spresenterRole",
                        "spresenterPresentationType","spresenterPresentationID","spresenterPresentationAbstract","spresenterPresentationAbstractQuality",
                        "spresenterPresentationUrl",'spresenterPresentationUrlQuality',"spresenterOralPoster","spresenterSessionTitle",
                        "spresentationDate","spresentationStartTime","spresentationEndTime","spresentationTitle","spresentationAbstract"]],
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the range that you are giving.
Try this:

```
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        auth,
        spreadsheetId,
        range: "test1!A:B",
        valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
        resource: {
            values: [
                [name, email]
            ],
        }
    })
```

Comment: sorry for re-opening old question but why it says: `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression`?